# Error no 1075 in mysql

Tags: mysql

While creating table in mysql administrator :-

```
CREATE TABLE `db`.`product` (
  `product_nm` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `count` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_nm`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

We came across error 1075 for auto increment of count variable. Please suggest another way of doing same without error in mysql administrator.

Comment: Show the actual error message

Answer (score 1):

You can't have auto increment field without specifying it as primary key.

If You want to have an auto-Incrementing column that is not the PRIMARY KEY, then there must be an index (key) on it, like below:

```
 CREATE TABLE members ( 
   `product_nm` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   `count` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`product_nm`)
   KEY (count)
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```